# Azure sign in not working using Azure Tools option in VSCode

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code

I installed the Azure Tools plugin (version: 0.0.4) for VSCode (version: 1.27.2). I have no proxy setting in my system. I validated it by running the command in cmd : netsh winhttp show proxy and found

Direct access (no proxy server).

I tried to login into Azure using the Azure Tools option present in the side bar, which caused a pop up to open at the bottom right corner. I clicked on the button with Copy and Open option which opened a browser instance where I copied the password details, post which when I came back to the VSCode window and then I see that I am still not logged in. I tried the above process multiple times but see the same again and again.

Can anyone help me to get some guidance on this to fix the issue?

[image]

Comment: Did you make any progress with this issue? I have the same problem but I use VSC 1.50.1 on macOS. From time to time I get prompt with code to login into azure but it never works, when typing I get "That code didn't work. Check the code and try again.". I may login from terminal azure-cli without problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and for me was the latest Azure Account plugin version **0.9.10**. It doesn't work.

I reinstalled the previous version **0.9.9** and now the login works again.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue when trying to login and extract an API from API management. Using Azure Sign In or Azure Login would open up the popup but the callback URL would not trigger a sign in VS Code. I tried everything to the point of reinstalling VS Code.

After messing around with the different Azure Sign In options, I finally got an error when trying to sign in to Azure Cloud. The error mentioned that my admin requires the use of a device code. Unfortunately this error is neither shown nor handled when using the default Azure Sign In command.

The fix for me was to expressly sign in using Azure Sign In with Device Code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce it with [**Azure Account** extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.azure-account) (0.4.3) for VSCode (version: 1.27.2).

If [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) is installed, please have a try to use `az login` to check whether it can login. If you can login with az command then close the VS code and open it to try again.

[image]

Comment: Still not working for me. I'm on VSC 1.29.1, azure cli installed and working.  I can log in with `az login`. VS Code launches the browser asking to log in and copies the code for me.  I enter the code in the browser, it tells me I'm done and I can close the browser now.  Still not signed into Azure inside VS Code, nothing happens.  Strange issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I am a member of several tenants for various orgs.

By updating my tenant Id in the Azure Account extension settings I was able to sign in.

I suspect I will have to update it when I want to work in a subscription owned by another tenant.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce, It does not work on Ubuntu,
no matter what I do.
I gave up, and moved to windows.
So 1:0 for Microsoft :-)
If something does not work with Azure:

1. try with windows
2. try with Edge

Its painful truth - they only support software they already own. Which make sense business-wise.